# Using indices to find an unknown

Tags: arithmetic

$1458^n = 2^n / 9$

I'm told to find the value of $n$. How to do that?

It is my first time encountering this type of problem when I can't find make every number a constant . What do I do here . Can I get a hint ? Thanks in advance

(2 x 3^6)^n x 3^2 = 2^n

Comment: It might be worth your while to find the prime factorization of $1458$

Comment: @user307640 Write 1458 as a power of 2.

Answer (score 3):

$$1458^n=\frac{2^n}{9}$$

$$729^n\cdot 2^n=\frac{2^n}{9}$$

$$729^n=\frac{1}{9}$$

$$9^{3n}=9^{-1}$$

$$3n=-1$$

$$n=-\frac{1}{3}$$